# Jenkins MSBuild plugin not working with cygwin on windows slave

Tags: windows, jenkins, msbuild, cygwin

I am trying to run msbuild on a slave with cygwin (the master is ubuntu)
I am getting the following error:

FATAL: /cygdrive/c/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe doesn't exist

The file does exist in the said location. (and I was case sensitive)

I have also installed the "cygpath" jenkins plugin, but I am still getting the same error

I also changed the path to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
but getting the same error (but with relevant path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that :
    c:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\MSBuild.exe

does the trick

Comment: The reason this works is that the character '\' is used to escape the next character. So you have to do '\\'.
The shell in cygwin is more than likely bash.